# My map gives me Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to do a map of my differents people but it gives me the error on the title

I don't really understand and there is my code:

```
export const Testt = ({ childs}) => {
    console.log(childs)
    return childs.map((element, index) => (
        //element

        <div>
            zdijiziojzadioj
        </div>
    )
    )
    }
```

and there is my childs

```
(12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: '619e7301e74b007f5c62482d', firstName: '', lastName: '', birth: '2020-11-19', genre: 'male', …}
1: {_id: '619fae3c96f85d2415d8fe24', firstName: '', lastName: '', birth: '2021-11-03', genre: 'male', …}
2: {_id: '619fae5296f85d2415d8fe28', firstName: '', lastName: '', birth: '2021-11-04', genre: 'male', …}
3: {_id: '619faec296f85d2415d8fe39', firstName: '', lastName: '', birth: '2021-11-04', genre: 'male', …}
4: {_id: '619faee196f85d2415d8fe40', firstName: '', lastName: '', birth: '2021-11-04', genre: 'male', …}
5: {_id: '619faf1496f85d2415d8fe4e', firstName: '', lastName: '', birth: '2021-11-04', genre: 'male', …}
...
length: 12
```

I don't understand where can be the problem, i already used the map but i have never had this problem,

Thanks for yours answer!

Comment: can you show us how are you passing props to Testt Component ?

Comment: It would help if you post the line in which you use the component Testt, and the exact error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably means that the value `childs` is not populated at the initial render.

What we usually do in React to circumvent this, is adding conditional statements.

This should do the trick -

```js
export const Testt = ({ childs}) => {
    console.log(childs)
    return childs && childs.map((element, index) => (
        //element

        <div>
            zdijiziojzadioj
        </div>
    ))
}
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything ;s

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error happens?

Comment: you were right, my child was not populated. I just had to change some thing in another function, Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome!